# Falha ao clonar repositório, erro: Repository test has failed

Tags: android-studio, bitbucket

Estou tentando clonar um repositório. Bitbucket. Porém dá esse erro:

> Repository test has failed

Em settings o caminho do git está correto.

Para criar eu tento criar no momento de abertura do Android Studio

- <kbd>Check out project from Version Control</kbd> > <kbd>Git</kbd>
- Digito as informações
- Vou em <kbd>Test</kbd>

Aí surge:

> Repository test has failed

também dá isso!

[image: também dá isso!]

Alguém sabe como resolver?

esse pelo cmd ...

[image: esse pelo cmd]

Comment: tem acesso ao git pela linha de comando??

Comment: sim, o erro está quando eu tento clonar o repositório.

Comment: tente assim na linha de comando. `git init; git clone -v git@bitbucket.org:usuario/repositorio.git` e veja o que acontece. Uma alternativa seria usar o SourceTree [https://www.sourcetreeapp.com]

Comment: esse é o que dá pelo cmd. [adicionei outra imagem]

Comment: tentando agora usar o SourceTree. Nele dá o mesmo erro quando tento clonar o mesmo repositório.

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado, pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

CONSEGUI. Depois de 2 dias inteiros de pesquisa, ufa. O erro estava no diretório de um certificado de segurança do próprio Git, não sei se foi erro no momento da instalação ou foi alterado com a instalação de outro software, mas o importante é que consegui alterando esse diretório (CAfile:) com a seguinte linha de comando:

```
> git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\git\bin\ca-bundle.crt"
```

Comment: Legal parabéns!

Answer (score 0):

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24625373/1518921) você deve ter que apontar o executável do `git`,

1. Baixe e instale o git: http://git-scm.com/downloads
2. Aponte o `git.exe` no AndroidStudio:

   - <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Version Control</kbd> > <kbd>VCSs</kbd> > <kbd>Git</kbd> > <kbd>Path to Git executable</kbd>:
   - Selecione (ou digite) o caminho pro executável, por exemplo: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe`

Comment: Faço exatamente isso. Mas o erro persiste. Vou adicionar uma outra imagem.

Comment: Sim! Da o mesmo!

Comment: windows 8 !!!!!

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado, pela ajuda!